# In self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController why self.storyboard is optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and xcode and while I am learning page transition there was something that I can't understand

```
guard let dvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController
```

In the code above why self.storyboard and self.navigationController is optional?

```
guard let dvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:"ViewControoler") as? ViewController else {
   return
}
```

Also, I don't understand the role of as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`storyboard` is optional because it's possible to instantiate view controller another way, e.g. from xib or programmatically, [link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621399-storyboard);
`navigationController` is optional since there can't be one, obviously;
`as` is used for type casting.

All these answers can be found in documentation, it would be much faster to look there at first